# How to recreate failed mails on odoo

Tags: python, email, odoo

Odoo incoming server is configured. out of 10 emails 8 emails successfully created as leads/tickets on odoo but 2 emails failed due to concurrency issue.
How to fetch failed 2 emails back on odoo?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to solve the concurrency issue instead?

Comment: Odoo receive unread emails, just  unread that 2 emails on your email inbox.